# problem with "sudo dpkg --configure -a"

Tags: apt, kubuntu, dpkg, 17.04

**Some Info:**

- Spanish Languange
- Kubuntu 17.04
- KDE Plasma: 5.9.4
- Kernel version:4.10.0.19-generic
- OS: 64 Bits
- Hardware: Intel Core i7-4700HQ --- CPU 2.40 Ghz

**Problem:**

I try to update with `sudo apt-get update` and everything is fine, but when i try to upgrade I get the following problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade    
E: No se pudo bloquear /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Recurso no disponible temporalmente)
E: No se pudo bloquear el directorio de administración (/var/lib/dpkg/), ¿quizás haya algún otro proceso utilizándolo?
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install -f` which is prescribed for other similar problems on the web. I also tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Searching my error messages led me to [this link](http://www.javiercarrasco.es/2013/02/08/no-se-pudo-bloquear-varlibdpkglock-open-11-recurso-no-disponible-temporalmente/).

I started following the steps there, but `sudo dpkg --configure -a` hangs:

```
$ sudo  dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq dpkg-dev
dpkg: error: base de datos de estado de dpkg está bloqueada por otro proceso
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                   
Obj:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                         
Obj:3 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                               
Obj:5 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                  
Des:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89,2 kB]                                         
Obj:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                      
Obj:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease                          
Obj:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease                        
Obj:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                         
Descargados 89,2 kB en 18s (4.827 B/s)                                                                             
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
xoktz@xoktz-ntb:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
E: No se pudo bloquear /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Recurso no disponible temporalmente)
E: No se pudo bloquear el directorio de administración (/var/lib/dpkg/), ¿quizás haya algún otro proceso utilizándolo?
xoktz@xoktz-ntb:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
E: No se pudo bloquear /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Recurso no disponible temporalmente)
E: No se pudo bloquear el directorio de administración (/var/lib/dpkg/), ¿quizás haya algún otro proceso utilizándolo?
xoktz@xoktz-ntb:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
E: No se pudo bloquear /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Recurso no disponible temporalmente)
E: No se pudo bloquear el directorio de administración (/var/lib/dpkg/), ¿quizás haya algún otro proceso utilizándolo?
xoktz@xoktz-ntb:~$ sudo fuser -vki  /var/lib/dpkg/lock
                     USUARIO        ORDEN DE ACCESO PID
/var/lib/dpkg/lock:  root       3375 F.... dpkg
¿Finalizar el proceso 3375 ? (y/N) y
xoktz@xoktz-ntb:~$ sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
xoktz@xoktz-ntb:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
E: se interrumpió la ejecución de dpkg, debe ejecutar manualmente «sudo dpkg --configure -a» para corregir el problema
xoktz@xoktz-ntb:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Configurando linux-headers-4.10.0-20-generic (4.10.0-20.22) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-20-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic
^CFailed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-4.10.0-20-generic.postinst line 110.
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete linux-headers-4.10.0-20-generic (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 2
Configurando iucode-tool (2.1.1-1) ...
Procesando disparadores para man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Configurando linux-image-4.10.0-20-generic (4.10.0-20.22) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-20-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-20-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-20-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-20-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic
```

The command `ps axjf` displays [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24788083/).

How should I proceed to get `sudo apt-get upgrade` working?

Comment: Seems in other similar problems that you must remove nvidia drivers but : https://paste.ubuntu.com/24788304/

I try sudo apt-get auto remove but gets againg stuck in "Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-20-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic"